# In Access form, is there a way to use a search box to populate the form using VBA?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have two solutions I've been working to solve this problem...

---

Attempt #1

I have a combo box in an Access form with two options, "All," and "All Sample." The Sample is a selection of records from my table that are flagged for review with a sample_record_id (text field) for identification with a non-zero positive number. "All" and "All Sample" are in my Row Source. My combo box is named myFilters.

Afterupdate, this VBA runs:

```
Private Sub myFilters_AfterUpdate()
Debug.Print myFilters.Value
  If myFilters.Value = "All Sample" Then
    Me.FilterOn = True
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "sample_record_id <> '0'"
  Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
  End If
End Sub
```

All records have an entry for sample_record_id.

I was expecting my sample records to populate when "All Sample" is selected, and all records to populate otherwise. In fact, all records do populate when "All" is selected, but when "All Sample" is selected, a "Enter Paramaters Value" dialog box appears with the text "sample_record_id" with a space for entering text.

Interestingly, when I switch the IF and ELSE:

```
If myFilters.Value = "All" Then
    Me.FilterOn = False
Else
    Me.FilterOn = True
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "sample_record_id <> '0'"
```

...neither selection works as expected.

---

Attempt #2

I also tried the following VBA:

```
Private Sub myFilters_AfterUpdate()
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM invoice_summary WHERE sample_record_id <> '0';"
  Debug.Print strSQL
  DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

I was expecting this to do the same thing as previous code, but no matter which selection I pick, a debug error pops up saying "A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of a SQL statement."

Debug of strSQL returns: SELECT * FROM invoice_summary WHERE sample_record_id <> '0';

I've tried it with and without the ;

The sql statement works in a standard query.

Is there a way to make either of these work?

Answer (score 0):

Been working on this for two days, and 30 minutes after I post I figure it out. Sigh.

Using my first attempt, I just had to put brackets around my field name:

```
Private Sub myFilters_AfterUpdate()
  If myFilters.Value = "All Sample" Then
    Me.FilterOn = True
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[sample_record_id] <> '0'"
  Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
  End If
End Sub
```